# Please explain the use of " 's"in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

You’ll figure things out along the way and your plan will need to change to adapt to your learning’s consistently

Comment: There's nothing to explain, because it's not even remotely valid English

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know if it's not *remotely* valid English...

Comment: The possessive case is "your" what the apostrophe s referring to ;sorry I have a lack of knowledge next to ignorance in the use of it

Comment: @dantiston: I haven't given the example sentence a great deal of thought even after glancing at it again now, but I can honestly say I currently have no real idea what the sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: What is the source of your example?

Comment: This is unquestionably a mistake--it should be *learnings*, a plural designating "the things that you learn". That use of *learning* is itself fairly novel, and largely restricted to folks in the field of education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of someone using "'s" incorrectly. Sometimes people accidentally use "'s" when they actually mean to just use the plural. However, in this case, even a plural is a little bit awkward. The sentence should probably be like this:

> You'll figure things out along the way and your plan will need to change to adapt to your learning consistently

Though `your plan will need to change to adapt to your learnings consistently` is also grammatical, just a little less common.

I would probably write (as a stylistic thing):

> You'll figure out things along the way. Your plan will need to change to consistently adapt to the things you learn.

Comment: I run into the usage of a redundant 's many times doubting my knowledge of English.Now that I get informed I can say that some English writers are obsessed on using the  's even when there is no need for it

Comment: Glad it helped @AhmadMoustafa -- feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel like this answers your question! Thanks!